# Generate Insert statement from pandas dataframe dynamically

Tags: python, dataframe, python-dataclasses

I found below code to generate insert statement dynamically for any dataframe. But it does not handle nan values and tries to insert nan instead of Nulls. 
How to handle nan values in this case? ( note- dataframe has around million records).

```
def SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT_FROM_DATAFRAME(SOURCE, TARGET):
    sql_texts = []
    for index, row in SOURCE.iterrows():       
        sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+TARGET+' ('+ str(', '.join(SOURCE.columns))+ ') VALUES '+ str(tuple(row.values)))        
    return sql_texts
```

Comment: Have u noticed pandas to_sql function.

Comment: Yes, I do not want to use to_sql because it does not provide any logs or any information about query which is executed .  I need all this information for logs.

Comment: Also to_sql does not have any option to ignore error in a particular row . If any row has loading error entire dataframe does not load in to_sql.

Answer (score 1):

replace() method doesn't do the job ?

```py
def SQL_INSERT_STATEMENT_FROM_DATAFRAME(SOURCE, TARGET):
    sql_texts = []
    for index, row in SOURCE.iterrows():       
        sql_texts.append('INSERT INTO '+TARGET+' ('+ str(', '.join(SOURCE.columns))+ ') VALUES '+ str(tuple(row.values)).replace("nan", "NULL"))        
    return sql_texts
```